# What is the function of ECS in airplane?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-systems

What is the function of ECS in airplane?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Your question title says ESC, but the body says ECS: which one is correct? It would also help if you can tell us which type of aircraft, and what the abbreviation stands for (if you know).

Comment: Related: [Why is air mixed with bypass air on the A/C of an aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24809/3201) with answers explaining how it works.

Comment: Do you mean Environmental Control System? If so, can you please edit to say that instead of just using the acronym? There are so many acronyms in aviation that a lot of them can mean different things in different contexts, especially if they're only 2 or 3 letters.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE.  The core of your question is made to expand and explain its title. You should expand it to provide further explanation of what you are looking for, possibly including  your current state of  understanding so that an appropriate level of explanation can be provided in answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is air mixed with bypass air on the A/C of an aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24809/why-is-air-mixed-with-bypass-air-on-the-a-c-of-an-aircraft)

Answer (score 3):

The ECS system is the [Environmental Control System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmental_control_system_(aircraft)).  It is the system that handles pressurization and thermal control of the aircraft. The [FAA has a nice handbook on it here.](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aircraft/amt_airframe_handbook/media/ama_Ch16.pdf) There is some more information on [how it works on the new 747-8 here](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/2012_q1/4/) that may be of interest.