# Where does the final cooling take place in the air cycle machine of the air conditioning system?

Tags: aircraft-systems, jet

On aircraft with an ACM air conditioning, where does the final cooling take place? Is it in the ACM expansion turbine or in the ACM compressor?

Comment: Specifically, please elaborate on what kind of air conditioning system you're referring to. Are we talking about airliners here? Single-engine pistons?

Comment: Yes,it is about jet engine a/c

Comment: Related, [the different temperatures in the a/c system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE7jc.png). The last cooling occurs at the turbine stage. From [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24809/why-is-air-mixed-with-bypass-air-on-the-a-c-of-an-aircraft/24820#24820).

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/13321/4108

Answer (score 4):

The final cooling will be at the turbine of the [ACM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_cycle_machine).

[image]
([Source](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/back-basics-aircraft-systems-air-conditioning-paulo-neto))

Air passes through two heat exchangers, before finally passing through the turbine of the ACM.

---

Related:

- [How hot would pressurized air get if the air conditioning failed?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/5031/14897)
- [Why is air mixed with bypass air on the A/C of an aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24809/14897)